# Capuring a screen of an exe than pops up for a few miliseconds

Tags: windows, capture

OK, indirectly related to programming, but does anyone know how to capture a a screen that pops up for a few milliseconds in Windows? (The screen popups up when I double click an exe) and then terminates the process.

Its too fast to actually focus on the information its bringing up, but it is defnintly saying something

Is there some kind of software than can playback screen in ultra slow motion?

Comment: I'm sure there are screen capture utilities that can do this, but SuperUser would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a console app or a winforms app? If it's a console app, you could drop to a command line and run it manually. Then you can clipboard the output.

Comment: Hi, its an exe, but it does bring up a command prompt interface, I will give it a go...